# How to upload dSYM to crashlytics if I'm not using Cocoapods?

Tags: ios, crashlytics

Crashlytics deprecated uploading dSYM file from the console. To upload dSYM using the script from terminal, the instruction is:

```
/path/to/pods/directory/Fabric/upload-symbols -gsp /path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /path/to/dSYMs
```

However, I'm using Carthage instead of Cocoapods. Does that mean I cannot upload dSYM file from terminal? I know I can also include a line in the build process to upload dSYM, but I want to know if running script from terminal is not for Carthage users.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You must use the path to the upload-symbols script relative to your framework folder. This is the link to the raw frameworks if you want to explore the folder structure. https://storage.googleapis.com/firebase-preview-drop/ios/crashlytics/com.crashlytics.ios-manual.zip